# Using arcpy to reclassify "NoData" to a value

Tags: arcpy, reclassify

There is a part in my Python script where I convert a Feature to a Raster (arcpy.FeatureToRaster_conversion). The output is a raster with a certain value (based on a field of the Feature). The rest of the extent of the resulting raster has "NoData" values.

However, I want that "NoData" to be 0. Here is the code.

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

raster = arcpy.Raster(export_path)
arcpy.sa.Reclassify(raster, "Value", arcpy.sa.RemapValue([["NoData", 0]]), "").save(export_path)
```

But this has no effect. I still have "NoData".

How do you reclassify "NoData" values to a numerical value using arcpy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a conditional instead:

```
reclassify = arcpy.sa.Con(arcpy.sa.IsNull(raster), 0, raster, "Value = 1")
reclassify.save(export_path)
```

This will evaluate a version of your raster where all NoData cells are changed to value 1 (the IsNull part). The Con part will then assign 0 if Value = 1 and the original raster values if false.

Comment: Just to you know, you can't append ".save(export_path)" at the end of the first line.

Comment: I was going to edit my post with the exact changes you proposed. Perfect!